# How to get String text from meta lyrics byte of file .mid?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, midi

When I am playing file **.mid** i am get byte of meta lyrics but I don't know how to get meta  lyric from this byte. Any one can help me the way to do this ? Thank for all comments.

```
void MyMIDIReadProc(const MIDIPacketList *pktlist, void *refCon, void *connRefCon) {

MIDIPacket *packet = (MIDIPacket *)pktlist->packet;

for (int i=0; i < pktlist->numPackets; i++) {
    Byte midiStatus = packet->data[4];
    Byte midiCommand = midiStatus >> 4;
    if (midiCommand == 0x05){
        NSLog(@"meta event 0x%x",midiCommand1);
        //how to get meta text here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're parsing the MIDI a bit incorrectly here. Check out this link, which has a good overview of the spec:

http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html

Anyways, MIDI lyrics events are technically MIDI Meta events (as your question's title would indicate that you already know). So the status code should be `0xFF` and the byte *after it* it will be `0x05`. The byte after that tells you how long the string is (in bytes).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have read but i could not understand how to take Meta event and get lyric string.